# Add new image field to Joomla 2.5 com_content

Tags: joomla2.5

I want to add new field for uploading file to com_content component for back-end in joomla 2.5.2. What would be the process for that for db related changes and files related changes? I have tried to generate a field with help of this 'echo $this->item->addfile; but it's not displaying any title or textbox or anything Please explain....
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid hacking the core like this. Doing so will cause issues when it is time to update your Joomla install. Any changes you make in the core will likely be overwritten in the update process.

Rather than hacking the core, there are several content construction kit type extensions that are a replacement for com_content. Zoo, K2, and Seblod support content item images out of the box and there are quite a few others that can probably do it with a little tinkering.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction